# Backbone.js Collection fetch with initial parameter

Tags: php, json, collections, backbone.js

Is there any way to fetch a collection by giving an initial model parameter to **fetch()**.

**To clear out:** I have a model Human with attributes **name** (as a string) and **numbers(array)**. I would like to find all the people in my database with given array of numbers. (**Example:** I have [123,342,4] in my array and for each number I would like to pull the people's name).

I've created a Human collection giving the model is **human**. And when I fetch like this it causes no problem;

```
humanCollection.fetch({
            success:function(model,response){
                console.log(model.toJSON().length);
                var arr=model.toJSON();
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                    console.log(arr[i].humanName+" ");
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error:function(model,response){
                console.log(response);
                console.log("Failure");
            }
        });
```

I'm thinking of creating a **dummy** human object with no name and just numbers and later on passing the numbers to my **php** but **.fetch()** function doesn't seem to work when I put a parameter to the beginning. Not even the code below works;

```
 humanCollection.fetch({},{
                success:function(model,response){
                    console.log(model.toJSON().length);
                    var arr=model.toJSON();
                    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                        console.log(arr[i].humanName+" ");
                    console.log("Success");
                },
                error:function(model,response){
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log("Failure");
                }
            });
```

What could be the problem? And is it logical for me to create a dummy human model in order to retrieve a collection of humans with the given numbers. That was the only way I could think of transferring the specific required json data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are messing up things.

As I understood the *numbers* are the `Human.ids` you want to fetch.

If this is correct these *numbers* have not any meaning to be part the the `Human` model. I rather will move them to the `Collection`.

You have to prepare the Collection to send a *filter* param in the *URL* of the `fetch` that informs to the *server layer* which Humans the Collection wants to fetch.

Also you have to prepare the *server layer* to be able to process the *filter* param with the *ids* of the Humans you want the server responses with.

So, in the Backbone Collection we can play with the `data` option of the `fetch()` method like this:

```
humanCollection.fetch({ data: { ids: [123, 342, 4] } });
```

The *server* will have to parse the `ids` param and return only the requested Humans.

Then in your Collection **you will only have your selected Humans** and you will can ask them for *name* or whatever.

Comment: Hi. `humanCollection.fetch({ data: { ids: [123, 342, 4] } });` will make string `ids%5B%5D=123&ids%5B%5D=342&ids%5B%5D=4` instead of `ids:123,342,4` Can you help me?